# How to change error icon's color in quasar q-input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, quasar-framework

[image]

How to change '!' icon's color ?

Answer (score 0):

To change the error icon's color specifically for a q-input in Quasar, you can utilize Quasar's built-in CSS classes and styles to customize the appearance of the error icon. Here's the best approach:

Quasar provides CSS classes that allow you to customize various aspects of its components, including icons. To change the error icon's color for a q-input, you can override the default error icon's color using CSS.
If the default CSS class isn't taking effect, try using more specific CSS selectors to override the color.

```
   q-input.custom-error-icon .q-field__error-icon {
  color: #ff0000; /* Change this color to your desired error color */
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Maybe there is an override somewhere?

Comment: updated the code. Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change quasar theme colors and styles, you can change variables in quasar.variables.scss in then src/css folder. For modify error color, you just need to override $negative sass variable in the variable file. Negative Default color is red.

For more information:
https://quasar.dev/style/sass-scss-variables

*If you just want to change icon color but not other negative color, you can use custom css in app.scss like this:*

```
.q-input.custom-error-icon .q-field__error-icon {
  color: #ddd
}
```